# What does action do in this context "<a href="file.php?action=lista">"

Tags: php, jquery, html

Could someone explain the "action" keyword found in the  tags below ?

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="file1.php">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="file2.php?action=lista">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="file3.php?action=old">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a request parameter...

Comment: It's an GET argument key/value that will be passed to the file2.php script if you click that link... I'd suggest you read a few basic PHP tutorials

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is passing a value to the PHP file, which the PHP file can then use in several ways. It can pass that value to a database, or just display it on the screen, or any number of things.

In PHP it can be accessed by `$_GET['action']`.

Comment: Is it passed using post, in other words file.php can access the value using $_POST variable ? Regards

Comment: @twimB: No, it'll be a `$_GET` value.

Comment: Yes, of course. I suppose I could have been a little more clear.

Answer (score 1):

That would completely depend on whatever code is on the server. It's merely sending a GET variable. The code on the server will decide what to do based on the value.